# Publishing site created with Laravel error

Tags: laravel, web, host

Hi there i follow this tutorial how to setup on the FreeWebHostingArea com :
If your domain is pointed to public_html directory then all content should placed in that directory. How ? let me tell you

> Copy all files and folders ( including public folder ) in public html
>   Copy all content of public folder and paste it in document root ( i.e.
>   public_html ) Remove the public folder Open your bootstrap/paths.php
>   and then changed 'public' => **DIR**.'/../public', into 'public' =>
>   **DIR**.'/..',
>
> and finally in index.php,
>
> Change
>
> require **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
>
> $app = require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/start.php'; into
>
> require **DIR**.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
>
> $app = require_once **DIR**.'/bootstrap/start.php';

but when i load the index i get this error

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '/home/vhosts/epernikhardware.eu5.org/vendor/composer/autoload_files.php'
>   (include_path='/home/vhosts/epernikhardware.eu5.org/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')
>   in
>   /home/vhosts/epernikhardware.eu5.org/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php
>   on line 47

And can amy one explain me how to easily get this simple site to work is it so hard to publish a few web pages with laravel framework. Please help

Comment: You need to upload your `vendor` folder.

Comment: But i upload it and all of his sub folders

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that hosting but for other hosting service such as `JustHost`, `GoDaddy`, `BlueHost`, `HostGator`... I deploy the Laravel web pretty much easy.

1) Access to the host via SSH, get the source code

```
$ cd www/     
$ git clone https://github.com/ME/MY-PROJECT.git .
```

2) Get Composer:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --filename=composer
```

3) Update all dependencies (`/vendor`)

```
$ composer update
```

4) Move the `/public/.htaccess` to the root

```
$ mv public/.htaccess .
```

That's all, site is ready. Perhaps, there are more steps in configuring the database but it is not necessary to mention here.

If you host your site on `Forge` or `DigitalOcean`, the process would be much easy, just add the source origin, and most of things will be done automatically.

Comment: Thx but im using windows and filezilla.And im not familiar with this type of settings  to get my web site working. Can you share a link with more instruction how to do this settings? And i prefer free web hosting because of my simple and under dev web site.

Comment: step 1 is to get source code, you can upload source code via FTP; step 2 and 3 is to get dependencies, run on your computer then upload the `vendor` directory to your host; step 4 is to move the `.htaccess` out of `public/` . There is nothing about windows or linux here.

Comment: moved .htaccess file to root, now the it says file not found.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the PHP version in your computer and the PHP version in the cpanel of your hosting site is the same. I also had the same problem and this helped me.